# Blender tutorial plate moves on differen axises when I try to move it on Z axis

Tags: objects

[image]

I tried using move tool and G Z but it's the same story

Comment: Did you rotate the plate after you created it? Is your tool axis set to “global“ or “local“ at the top of the 3-D view?

Comment: I may said it a bit wrong. I didn't rotate it. When i try to move it upwards it clips to this position as shown in the photo and when i try to center it it just moves down

Comment: It seems rather strange. Do you have snap turned on (small magnet icon next to the axis setting mentioned)

Comment: Thank you that fixed the problem!